# iOS 13 Silent Push notification method not getting called application:, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:, fetchCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying to send silent pushes in iOS13 when I stumbled across an issue. This only happens in iOS 13. This is how my payload looks,

```
> POST /3/device/<MY DEVICE TOKEN> HTTP/2
> Host: api.sandbox.push.apple.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> content-type: application/json
> authorization: bearer MY_KEY
> apns-topic: MY_BUNDLE_ID
> apns-push-type: background
> apns-priority: 5
> Content-Length: 55
```

This is how my body looks,

```
{"aps":{"content-available":1,"sound":null,"alert":""}}
```

When the app is in foreground the method gets called but when I background the app, the method is not called at all. Even when the app is terminated, still the same issue.

Am I doing something wrong here, I have,

1. Enabled "Push Notifications" and "Background Modes -> Remote Notifications" in Capabilities tab.
2. I have registered for notifications in didFinishlaunchingWithOptions
3. Changed the payload without alert or sound keys and with a 0 badge

Nothing seems to work! Can anyone help me?

Comment: If your app not running and you receive notification, you have to tap that notification n get its data from ‘didFinishedLunchingWithFinishOption’ lunchOptions.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to send a Silent Notification like this, It will not send an alert but will call the method (Which is not happening)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app